# PDF file not rendering on HTML from Spring

Tags: angularjs, spring, pdf

I am trying to render pdf file from Spring controller in my browser. My Controller returns the data but the pdf is not rendered. My text file on the same page works. Please advise.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/showpdf", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public void showPDFFile(@RequestBody FilePath filePath, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
                File file = new File(filePath);

                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() +"\""));
            response.setContentLength((int)file.length());

            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, output);
            output.flush();
```

}

My Frontend Angular controller does a simple post request:

```
$http.post('/showpdf', selectedFile).success(
                            function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                            });
```

My HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body ng-controller="reportController">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data track by $index">
      <td ng-repeat="y in x track by $index">{{ y }}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The response from the server is 200 and I am able to see byte data in browser tools.

Comment: why are you using ajax for a pdf? did you try iframe?

Comment: I did try that as well but the path has to be generated from the server which the iframe is not taking

Comment: Why won't iframe take it?

Comment: I tried giving the absolute path on the server like this: `<iframe height="1000px" width="100%" type="application/pdf" src="/home/graph.pdf">` It says file not found :( I thought it could not render files on the app server from the local machine, that's why tried other way.

Comment: did you try including domain? iframe needs full url

Comment: The format for this will be? something like:  `http://url:portno/absolute path` or something else?

Comment: exact same as if you opened it in address bar of browser

Comment: But the file is remote server..how can I get that in absolute path?

Comment: don't understand problem...can you open it in a browser?

Comment: I am trying to access pdf file on Web server through my Web application. The path I know is absolute path on the Web server. I don't how to access that from my Web app

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code to use AngularJS Blob for rendering the pdf. Could not get the code asked in this post to work. Hope this helps someone.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/showpdf", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/octet-stream")
        @ResponseBody
        public byte[] showPDFFile(@RequestBody FilePath filePath, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
                  return org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);             
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <object data="{{content}}" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 1000px;"></object>
</div>
```

Angular Controller:

```
$http.post('/showpdf',{responseType: 'arrayBuffer'}).success(
                            function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                                var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                                   var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                                   $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileURL);

                            });
```